# BS4: Change modal on close animation

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

guys.
It's basically class-switching. When the modal opens, jQuery switches the class and vice versa. When I look into inspector it changes the class but the modal is closed in an instant without dramatic animation. I'm using animate.css by the way

This is the code:

```
$('#tambahModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#tambahModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('modal-dialog animated fadeOut').addClass('modal-dialog animated bounceIn');
});

$('#tambahModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#tambahModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('modal-dialog animated bounceIn').addClass('modal-dialog animated fadeOut');
});
```

Thank you

Comment: You forgot to mention what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: like I said earlier in the title, I want to change the default behavior of modal on close animation. I want to customize it using animate css. but it doesn't work as expected. the modal is closed in a blink without any dramatic closure